# Error in Mapproxy Tile generation for some map zoom level

Tags: python, wms, mapproxy

I am using mapproxy to generate my map tile with wms configration as source, which is working fine for certain zoom level. But for zoom level like from 3 to 8 the map tile is not getting fully generated even waiting for long time. 
Giving the tile output here
[image]
To get rid of this problem, I thought of implementing mapproxy-seeds configration, But getting some error like this:

Start seeding process (1 task)
  myseed1:
    Seeding cache 'latlong_cache' with grid 'webmercator' in EPSG:3857
    Limited to coverage in: -180.00000, -85.05113, 180.00000, 85.05113 (EPSG:4326)
    Levels: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    Overwriting: no tiles
[15:53:22]  3   0.00% -20037508.34279, -20037508.34279, 20037508.34279, 20037508.34279 (0 tiles)

An error occured. Retry in 2 seconds: IOError(13, 'Permission denied'). Retries left: 100

An error occured. Retry in 2 seconds: IOError(13, 'Permission denied'). Retries left: 100

An error occured. Retry in 4 seconds: IOError(13, 'Permission denied'). Retries left: 99

An error occured. Retry in 4 seconds: IOError(13, 'Permission denied'). Retries left: 99

An error occured. Retry in 8 seconds: IOError(13, 'Permission denied'). Retries left: 98

An error occured. Retry in 8 seconds: IOError(13, 'Permission denied'). Retries left: 98

An error occured. Retry in 16 seconds: IOError(13, 'Permission denied'). Retries left: 97

An error occured. Retry in 16 seconds: IOError(13, 'Permission denied'). Retries left: 97

An error occured. Retry in 32 seconds: IOError(13, 'Permission denied'). Retries left: 96

Here I am giving my seed.yaml and mapproxy.yaml configration.
seed.yaml

`seeds:
  myseed1:
    caches: [latlong_cache]
    levels:
      from: 3
      to: 8`

mapproxy.yaml

`services:
  demo:
  tms:
    use_grid_names: true
    origin: 'nw'
  kml:
      use_grid_names: true
  wmts:
  wms:
    md:
      title: MapProxy LatlongWMS Proxy
      abstract: This is a minimal MapProxy example.
    srs: ['EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:31467']
    bbox_srs: ['EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:31467']

layers:
  - name: latlong
    title: Latlong WMS - latlong.in
    sources: [latlong_cache]

caches:
  latlong_cache:
    grids: [webmercator]
    sources: [latlong_wms]

sources:
  latlong_wms:
    type: wms
    req:
      url: http://ip_address:81/cgi-bin/moon_map/qgis_mapserv.fcgi
      layers: world,landcovers,area,states,intersections,roads,way_points
      transparent: true
      transparent_color: '#d4d4c8'

grids:
    webmercator:
        base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR`

Please anyone suggest me any solution for this.

One other isuue is that initialy at any zoom level the mapproxy is generating tile at very slow rate and taking too much time to load.So how can i fasten the initial map tile load.

How can I get rid of all these issues?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out what was the isuue with the error while maptile generation at this zoom level so want to share my experience here. Actually the problem was with my wms sorce where i had configured for different layers. Among those layers one of the layer was taking time to load so other layer was also waiting for the response to complite by mapproxy. Once i removed that layer with mapproxy wms sorce configration. I got good map tile at that zoom level which is cached in my perticular DIR. Later on i added it for lower zoom level tile generation and got quick responce with less feature count. So this issue got solved this way. Here i am adding the generated maptile
[image]